# Datasets with time stamps in animal vocalisations (onset times/onset and offset/inter-{call, click, syllable}-intervals), any suggestions?

Tags: dataset, annotations, time-stamps

I'm looking at the statistics of inter-{call, click, syllable, onset}- intervals in animal vocalizations. Would anyone know where I could find such datasets?

These could be the annotation files with the (A) onset times, (B) onset and call duration (e.g. [zf4f](https://figshare.com/articles/dataset/Zebra_finch_group_calling_zf4f/1613791)), (C) onset and offset or the (D) intervals themselves.

Comment: Could you please rephrase the question title into a question? Currently it reads as a broad statement - which means people won't get a quick gist of what is being sought. Also, please share any previous attempts at solving the question beforehand.

Comment: This sort of seems like a do my homework for me request. No reason why the OP is asking or why it would be useful to know. Not sure it’s the best use of this forum?

Comment: @Ljfreer one way this forum might be different from e.g. Stack Overflow is that bioacoustics researchers will have questions about datasets. I think asking others in the community about datasets would be a great use of the forum. In my field of behavioral neuroscience it is a recurring issue that people are unaware of what datasets are available that could save them effort

Comment: @NickleDave I wonder what would be a good *answer*? I can think of a couple of examples to add to your answer, but - should I add my own answer, or edit your answer, or...?

Comment: Hi @DanStowell one thing I see on SO a lot is "in addition to the answer from @\person here's additional examples X, Y, Z". I'm open to feedback or edits, not sure why I got voted down--maybe it was the lengthy list of citations I had in my original answer.

Comment: Are you interested in any animal?

Answer (score 4):

Good question.

> This could be the annotation files with the (A) onset times, (B) onset and offset or the (C) intervals themselves.

I'm not aware of any datasets with the intervals themselves, but there are a couple of resources that list datasets including annotation files with onset and offset times.

One is:
https://bioacousticsdatasets.weebly.com/
(that includes other bioacoustics datasets as well)

Another is this paper:
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s42991-021-00222-2
(see appendix A)
https://blumsteinlab.eeb.ucla.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/104/2022/04/Linhart_etal_2022_MammBiol.pdf

which in addition to the Bioacoustics Dataset site also includes many datasets originally cited in Sainburg  et al. 2020:
https://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1008228#sec034

A public Zotero group that includes the cited datasets there as well as others is here: https://www.zotero.org/groups/4722497/annotated-vocalization-datasets

To work with these annotations and compute the interval times, you may find this Python tool helpful:
https://crowsetta.readthedocs.io/en/latest/